# How do I manually downsample something?

Tags: png

So I've got a still image (.PNG) that I want to downsample from a higher resolution to 1080p so it will look crisper.

Does anyone know of any programs that are capable of doing this? I couldn't find any.

Comment: Manually? Or automatically?

Comment: "Resolution" is the number of pixels per unit. "1080p" ("ixels"?) sounds like you are really trying to downsample from a larger *size*, not "resolution". Anyway: Adobe Photoshop can do that, and offers different strategies for downsampling.

Comment: What software do you have to use?

Comment: The title said manually, which is what I wish to do. I realize there's a difference between pixels and resolution, allow me to explain in a little further detail. I have a camera that takes pictures in (raw) 4000x3000. I want to downgrade this, resolution/pixels and all, to a lower size so that it will look more crisp.

Comment: @Jonware, Actually 1080p is a display resolution unit, I understand it specificly a video resolution HD, 1920x1080px.

Comment: Can you expand on the "manually" part some more? Do you mean other than "using a Resize option", which is *common* in all image editing software? (Even the lowly MS Paint...)

Comment: Manually would mean you color pixels yourself one at a time.

Comment: I didn't ask how to manually make a photo, I simply asked how to take a larger one and downsize it EXACTLY how Graphics cards downsample extremely high resolution real-time renders to fit whatever monitor you currently have. I didn't want to resize, I want to use the same method. Such method is explained here: http://tinyurl.com/cd5qlph

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Practicly any decent program can do that but you have to control the process.

After resampling you can apply some sharpening.

For example on Gimp try resampling with "cubic" or "Lanczos" interpolation and use "Unsharp Mask". In Photoshop try "Automatic" or "Bicubic Sharper" and then "Smart Sharpen".

If your original file is too blurry you can try, either sharpening it before resamppling it or using a "none" in gimp or "nearest neighborg" in Photoshop when resampling it. (Apply the sharp after resampling again as described before)